# Could I retrieve Facebook page stories without login on iOS?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have iOS native app , need to display stories from Facebook fan pages , currently I have to enforce users to login to Facebook throw my App to see the page posts , is there a way to let them see the posts without enforcing them to login ? specially the page is public and I can open it from any web browser without login.

Comment: You will need an access token for the request. You could use an app or page access token – but both of those should never be exposed in client-side code, so that should be handled server-side. If that’s not possible, then making users login so that you can use their user access token is the only viable option.

Comment: But what I need to do doesn't need page access toke , just query the page stories no editing , deleting or adding stories required .
And if I open page from the web browser I can see story without login.

Comment: It needs an access token, because all API requests (besides those for profile pictures) now do. And what you can see directly on facebook.com has little to do with what you can see via API, those are two largely different things.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution for this issue as follow
you can use your appID|App_secret as an access token , this will enable the retrieval of any content without enforcing the users to login
but this is not safe to be used from the client side since this URL can be intercepted and app secret being revealed.

The saver implementation is to use this on server side and work as proxy between the client application and FB API.